# How to make clang-format line break in comments instead of in code?

Tags: clang-format

I have lines similar to this in my C++ code:

```
#define MY_FILE_EXTENSION "foo"  //!< file extension of all files that ... very long comment
uint8_t _u8CurrentFileIdx;  //!< Very long comment, that exceeds the max column limit
```

clang-format inserted a line breaks like this:

```
#define MY_FILE_EXTENSION \
   "foo"  //!< file extension of all files that ... very long comment
uint8_t 
   _u8CurrentFileIdx;  //!< Very long comment, that exceeds the max column limit
```

I would expect, that line breaks in comments are preferred compared to line breaks in code.
This should be adjustable by penalties, but I can't find such penalties for "defines" and "between variable type and variable name"

Comment: Put comments above declarations. It's better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Using a .clang-format with only `PenaltyBreakComment: 0`, the second line formats as intended:

```cpp
#define MY_FILE_EXTENSION                                                      \
  "foo" //!< file extension of all files that ... very long comment
uint8_t _u8CurrentFileIdx; //!< Very long comment, that exceeds the max column
                           //!< limit
```

However, I don't see a way to format the first line as intended.